# Asymptotic behaviour of a non-linear differential equation in Gravitation

Tags: general-relativity, perturbation-theory, differential-equations, modified-gravity

I have been recently working on modifications to General Relativity, by adding new curvature terms in the Lagrangian density of the theory. In one of these theories (Einsteinian Cubic Gravity), the correction to Schwarzschild solution due to these new terms implies a third order non-linear differential equation for the $f(r)$ function (see Eq. (2.8) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.06675), which has no analytical solution. The authors then propose an inverse $r$ powers series expansion to study the asymptotic behaviour of the solution (i.e. for large $r$), and they substitute it into the equation for $f(r)$, obtaining an expression for $f(r)$ which depends only on a single parameter $b_1$.

A differential equation of third order should contain 3 integration constants, i.e. 3 free parameters, if we don't apply boundary conditions. However, this solution appears only with 1 parameter. I guess that studying the behaviour for large $r$ is restricting the parameter space, but I don't get why there are not 3 parameters, as it should be for a third order differential equation.

Comment: On this site we prefer that, if possible, you link to the *abstract page* for the document rather than the document itself.  It may also help you get answers if you post the equations involved using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help!